Unable to Invoke composeTrigger Function and Triggers Fail to Update Signature Quotes in Compose Email Popup Without Page Reload
We are currently experiencing an issue with the Signature quotes not updating in real-time. Presently, the Signature updates are only reflected after reloading the page. Our goal is to achieve real-time updates without requiring a page reload. We want, when we open the compose email popup, it displays the latest Signature quotes without needing a page reload
We have also tried using Gmail addon Trigger options, and while the triggers and function code are operational, we are unable to see real-time updates without having to refresh the page.
Our sample code, Updating Signature quotes is this Code.gs file
async function startApp() {
  let card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  let attribute = await getAttribute();
  let att = attribute.data[0];
  let ancer = att.attribute;
  // card.addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(ancer)));
  let newsResult = await getUsedSignatures();
  if (newsResult && newsResult.data.length > 0) {
    let signatures = newsResult.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < signatures.length; i++) {
      var daySection
      if (i === 0) {
        daySection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader("<b>Today</b>");
      }
      else if (i === 1) {
        var daySection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader("<b>Tomorrow</b>");
      }
      else {
        daySection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader(`<b>${signatures[i].used_date}</b>`);
      }
      let cleanedQuote = signatures[i].quote;
      daySection.addWidget(CardService.newTextParagraph().setText(`<i style="color: #484643; font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;">${cleanedQuote}</i>`));
      let switchFieldName = `toggle_switch_${signatures[i].id}`;
      let defaultSwitchValue
      if (signatures[i].toggle === "TRUE") {
        defaultSwitchValue = true
      }
      else {
        defaultSwitchValue = false
      }
      let switchDecoratedText = CardService.newDecoratedText()
        .setText("")
        .setWrapText(true)
        .setSwitchControl(CardService.newSwitch()
          .setFieldName("quote_select")
          .setValue(switchFieldName)
          .setSelected(defaultSwitchValue)
          .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction()
            .setFunctionName("handleToggleSwitchChange")
            .setParameters({ switchName: switchFieldName })));
      daySection.addWidget(switchDecoratedText)
      card.addSection(daySection);
    }
    updateGmailSignature(signatures[0].quote, ancer, signatures[0].toggle);
  } else {
    card.addSection(CardService.newCardSection());
  }
  return card.build();
}

function updateGmailSignature(newSignature, ancer, switchFieldName) {
  if (switchFieldName === "TRUE") {
    let userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    let profileSignature = {
      sendAsEmail: userEmail,
      signature: `${newSignature}\n${ancer}`
    };
    try {
      let response = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.patch(profileSignature, 'me', userEmail);
      Logger.log(response);
      Logger.log('Signature updated successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log('Error updating signature: ' + error);
    }
  } else {
    // If the toggle is off, remove the signature
    let userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    let profileSignature = {
      sendAsEmail: userEmail,
      signature: ''
    };

    // Use the Gmail API to update the signature
    try {
      let response = Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.patch(profileSignature, 'me', userEmail);
      Logger.log(response);
      Logger.log('Signature removed successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log('Error removing signature: ' + error);
    }
  }
}


Google Apps Script can't edit Gmail drafts in real time because the changes are done on the server rather than the client.
You might have to use a web browser extension instead of a Google Workspace add-on for adding the signature in real-time.
